# How to re-use a React library with hooks

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, react-hooks

**I'm writing my own library to help building forms with React.**

The goal is to be able to re-use it in any React application (made from scratch, with *create-react-app*, *nextjs*, other ?)

**My problem is that I can't firgure out how to re-use it.**

Here is the first issue I encountered when I tried to reuse my library in another project :

> Invalid Hook Call Warning

React says that the reason could be one of the following :

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

After investigation, I've excluded points `1.` and `2.`

I was using *Parcel* in the first place to build my library but I needed to exclude React from the bundle to solve `3.`

That's why I switched to *Webpack* and moved the *React* dependency to the `peerDependencies` + `devDependencies`.

I've tried different webpack configurations :

```js
const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  ...
  externals: {
    react: 'React'
  }
}
```

--> which leads to the following error in the consuming application :

> React is not defined

```js
const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  ...
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      amd: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      umd: 'react',
    }
  }
}
```

--> which leads to the following error :

> Cannot read property 'createContext' of undefined

I've tried to use my library with npm link and also by publishing it on npm but the result is the same.

Step to reproduce :

1. Install `@mlaopane/formhook` in your react application (`npm i @mlaopane/formhook` or `yarn add @mlaopane/formhook`)
2. Try to use a component, for example

```
import { Form } from '@mlaopane/formhook'

export default function App() {
  return <Form />
}
```

3. You should see the error in the console

Thank you for helping me with this :)

NB: This is my first issue, please tell if more information is needed.

Answer (score -1):

I've finally found a solution, inspired by [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library).

It looks like *Rollup* is a better candidate for bundling **React** libraries.

Even if I still can't link my library locally, it can be used when published.